# How to make Apache allow an executable to run?

Tags: php, apache

I am just wondering what I can do in this situation. 
I have this simple web page, through which I want to invoke a program that leaves a file on site. 
For your information, this web page itself can write (it saves uploaded files in a specific location in the server). 
But the problem is that when I invoke the program via the web page, it doesn't produce a file in the same specific location the web page succeeded to leave a file.

Simply speaking, my situation is 
a web page can save a file to folder A, 
but when the web page invokes a program to leave a file in the folder, it can't. 
And the question is
how I can make the program to do so when it's invoked by the web page?

Thanks, 
HJ.

Comment: bet you a million bucks its a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the folder permissions to allow write access for apache. From the command line in linux:

```
sudo chmod 644 path/to/folder
```

You should probably allow the apache group to own that folder, as well.

```
sudo chown yourlinuxusername:apache path/to/folder
```

Apache may have a different name, too. In such a case, just change apache to whatever the name should be.